# Css not load in Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code file in Codeigniter, but the URL method doesn't work also try so really I don't see problem here.

`<?= link_tag('asstes/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>`
load through helper `$this->load->helper('html');`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this way:- base_url('path/to/stylesheet.css');

Comment: How did you go did you try my answer

Answer (score 1):

On **CodeIgniter 3 versions** Just check if your base_url is set because some times having that blank can cause links not to work properly.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your-project/';
```

Controller example: Welcome.php

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();

      $this->load->helper('html');
   }

   public function index() {

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');

   }

}
```

Or auto load html helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');
```

In your head tag on view [link_tag guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag)

```
<html>
<head>
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>
</head>
```

Folder Example

```
application

assets

system

index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your string path

```
asstes ---> assets
```

I think it's better to write your own helper for add your resources (js, css...)